# No overload for method 'Join' takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#

What he wants me to do here for Join can you help me solve the problem?

```
 this.Parts
.Join(this.PartInformation, p => p.PartId, pi => pi.PartId, (p, pi) => new
{
    p.ListId,
    p.PartId,
    pi.PartDescription
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to join? That's the method for combining 2 sequences into one.

Comment: Which one are you trying to call? `Enumerable.Join` or `string.Join`?

Comment: I am fairly sure you are trying to do `string.Join(";", x.Select(a => a.UrlPrefix))`

Comment: Also, please post the text of error message, not images of them.

Comment: Does the updated code result in the same error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the static [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join) method instead:

```
.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => string.Join(";", x.Select(a => a.UrlPrefix)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature suggests you need to use [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-6.0):

```
var result = data
   .GroupBy(x => x.DomainId)
   .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => string.Join(";", x.Select(a => a.UrlPrefix)));
```